# wordpress 404 Not Found pages aren't displayed, just a blank page is shown

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

I've read many posts here with regards to the 404 pages being displayed as blank, but can't seem to find anything that has resolved the problem.

And, I'm hoping there is someone here with another suggestion.

Setup

```
IIS 6, PHP 5.2, Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite, and latest version of WordPress.
Custom permalinks enabled as /%postname%/
IIS 404 custom error page set to /index.php?error=404
Debugging enabled
```

Problem:
All the links and corresponding pages work as expected, apart from invalid or bad urls, that should be displaying my 404 page. Instead I get a blank page. The header looks fine, ie. 404 Not Found, but the body doesn't exist.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Uninstal all themes and plugins and try again.

Comment: WE have resolve the issue, we have transfer the site iis6 to iis 7, and now its working fine.

Comment: Please write that into an answer below and accept it later. That will mark your question as answered *and* makes the solution more prominent. And it's well accepted, you can answer your own questions here. Thank you for making this site better!

Answer (score 0):

We have resolved the issue, we transfered the site from IIS 6 to IIS 7, and now its working fine.